# Reading Json array into a listbox in Delphi 10.3

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I have the result of my Json API call to something like this (set of Order Ids)

```
[
    2258,
    2259,
    2260
]
```

I need to read this into a list so I can loop around it.
I am using Delphi 10.3

Comment: Your question lacks the code with which you have tried to solve the problem. So what have you tried? What was the result? If it failed, how did it fail?

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer I thought I share it in here.

```
procedure GetOrderIDs(sStr: String); // sStr is my Schema result
var
  m_JSONObject: TJSONArray;
  I: Word;
begin
  m_JSONObject := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sStr), 0) as TJSONArray;
  for I := 0 to m_JSONObject.Size - 1 do
  begin
    ListBox1.Items.Add(m_JSONObject.Items[i].Value);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `ParseJSONValue()` has an overload the takes a `String`, so you don't need to convert to UTF-8. And you are leaking the `TJSONArray`, you need to `Free()` it (preferably in a `try..finally`) when you are done using it. And you should be using `Integer` instead of `Word`

Comment: The datatype `Word` is dangerous: if `m_JSONOBject.size` is `0` the loop will run 65536 times. That's why one should use `Integer` right away when using any `-1` logic.